# Github tool to validate links in markdown

Tags: github, hyperlink, readme

What I plan to do in some of my `README.md` files is provide hyperlinks to other sites that I cite. However, we all run into that problem when links die or get moved, and said link becomes invalidated. =(

Is there a github tool that can run nightly checks to see if all the links in a `README.md` file (or something similar) are working correctly?

What I'm looking for is something that has a feature similar to Travis CI, where a project could have a badge saying "link-passing" on the project's main github page. (Example: [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) has those two classy looking "build-passing" badges.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want to use is [awesome_bot](https://github.com/dkhamsing/awesome_bot).

It doesn't provide the badge you want but it does check URLs in files.

Comment: Looks like you could get travis to run the tests for you. There wouldn't be a separate badge specifically for URLs, but oh well. I think this would probably be sufficient enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what I get from your question, Travis is actually enough to do the checking task.

I have already implemented it in [this project](https://github.com/onebithq/awesome-onebit). It's based on nodejs package named `grunt-deadlink`, Travis-CI configuration is also included. Unfortunately it doesn't support nightly test (as far as I know).

For shiny badge you can simply use this [badge generator service](http://shields.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that could also be integrated in your CI-Pipeline is [mlc](https://github.com/becheran/mlc).

I integrated it in the pipeline of another [project of mine](https://github.com/becheran/ntest/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)

The *mlc* link checker is written in rust and fairly fast by using async calls to check web links.