# check relative github links

Tags: python, github, markdown, relative-path

My end goal is to check whether all of the (relative) links in markdown files in a [github](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes#relative-links-and-image-paths-in-readme-files) project are still valid.

I couldn't find a utility that already does this--does one exist? If not, pointers to the simplest-possible scripts (python or shell preferred) to

1. Extract all (relative) links from markdown files
2. Expand relative links
3. Check the resulting URLs

would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github tool to validate links in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176318/github-tool-to-validate-links-in-markdown)

Comment: It does not; the accepted answer there doesn't handle relative links. (I'd tried `dkhamsing/awesome_bot` prior to posting.) But that's exactly the type of functionality that I'd otherwise be interested in.